# Get file path from a NSBundle which is not the mainBundle

Tags: ios, swift, nsbundle

I'm trying to get a `pathForResource` for a `plist` file, when the file was in the mainBundle it was easy, i used:

`let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist")`

But now i moved the `settings` file to another bundle and i don't know how to get it. I tried to use `forClass` and `allBundles` but i'm a swift rookie and didn't managed to make it work. Also coulden't find the solution over the web. It seems all the `NSBundle` usages examples is only for `mainBundle`

Comment: will you please show directory structure in xcode. From where to where you moved the file in bundles?

Comment: do you know in which bundle you have moved the resouce?

Comment: Well i'm not sure what you mean. Maybe my explanation is not correct. I changed the file target membership from the current to an embedded binary named ``Kit``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know which bundle has your resource you could loop through all of them:

```
let bundles = NSBundle.allBundles()

var path : String?
var myBundle : NSBundle?

for bundle in bundles {
    if let resourcePath = (bundle as! NSBundle).pathForResource("Settings", ofType: "plist") {
        path = resourcePath
        myBundle = bundle
        break
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you do have the `path` or the `identifier` of your bundle you could use:

```
let bundle = NSBundle(path: "the-bundle-path")

or

let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: "bundle-identifier")
```

This has nothing to do with the level of your Swift programming knowledge, rather with the interface `NSBundle` exposes. You should check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/allBundles) out to see if they can help you.

Comment: Already tried the docs... wasn't very helpful. Anyway ``let bundle = NSBundle(identifier: "bundle-identifier")`` worked! Thanks!